# Discontinuity of composite function $f(g(x))$ where $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x-2}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, continuity

> If $f$ and $g$ are both real valued functions such that $f(g(x))$ is defined at $c$. If $g$ is continuous at $c$ and $f$ is continuous at $g(c)$, then $f(g(x))$ is continuous at $x=c$.

This is fine. But, what if either of the functions is discontinuous ?

What can we say about $f$ and $g$ if $h$ is continuous or discontinuous ?

**Ex:1**

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x+2}$

In my reference it is said that $f(f(x))$ is discontinuous at $x=-2$ and $x=-5/2$. The observation seems to come from the fact that

$f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=-2$ and $\frac{1}{x+2}=-2\implies x=-5/2$

But, $f(f(x))=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x+2}+2}=\frac{x+2}{2x+5}$ seems to be discontinuous only at $x=-5/2$.

**Ex:2**

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x-2}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$

It is said to be discontinuous at $x=1/2, 1, 2$. Pls check [link](http://clay6.com/qa/21628/find-the-points-of-discontinuity-of-y-large-frac-where-u-large-frac) or check [Problem](http://ibb.co/bSG1Bc), [Solution](http://ibb.co/iufpxH)

But,
$$
f(g(x))=\frac{1}{g^2+g-2}=\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{x-1})^2+(\frac{1}{x-1})-2}=\frac{(x-1)^2}{1+x-1-2x^2+4x-2}\\
=\frac{-(x-1)^2}{2x^2-5x+2}=\frac{-(x-1)^2}{(x-2)(x-\frac{1}{2})}
$$
seems to be discontinuous only at $x=2$ and $x=1/2$.

**Ex:3**

If the observation given in my reference is correct does that mean that in the case where $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$,

$f(f(x))=\frac{1}{1/x}=x$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.

**Note:** Thanx @Andrew Li ,@Math_QED ,@Rob Arthan for their remarks.

My observations are based on the definition that

A real function $f$ is continuous at a point $c$ in the domain if $\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=f(c)$ and

A function is said to be discontinuous (or to have a discontinuity) at some point when it is not continuous there. These points themselves are also addressed as discontinuities, check [Real-valued continuous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function)
. ie, if

1.) $\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)$ exists but are not equal.

2.) $\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)$ exists and are equal, but not equal to $f(a)$.

3.) $f(c)$ is not defined.

Comment: You are wrong. All the functions you consider are continuous on their domain

Comment: @Math_QED so u mean saying $\frac{1}{x+2}$ is discontinuous at $x=-2$ is wrong ?

Comment: Yes. -2 is not in the domain, so it doesn't make sense to talk about continuity at that point

Comment: @Math_QED So infinite and removable discontinuities don't exist?

Comment: Where do I claim that?

Comment: You need to give some more context. What is the reference you mention. In dealing with linear fractional transformations, it is common to deal with functional composition formally (or algebraically) as you did, so that $f(f(x))$ would be treated as $x \mapsto (x+2)/(2x+5)$ which is finite and continuous at $-2$ but not at $-5/2$. Your reference seems to be wrong about $-5/2$.

Comment: @Math_QED: you (possibly rightly, as we don't have the context) are not taking into account the usual conventions for dealing with linear fractional transformations, whereby the OP's $f(f(x))$ is taken to be defined (i.e., finite) for $x = -2$, even though $f(-2)$ is not defined (i.e., not finite).

Comment: @RobArthan thanx for commenting. pls check i have edited the original post and i have added one link.

Comment: @Math_QED pls check the link added, which has a similar problem as in my reference.

Comment: The link you have provided would require me to pay to see the content. It looks to me like your course is not applying the usual conventions for linear fractional transformations, but you are. I.e., you are simplifying $f(f(x))$ algebraically and then concluding that it is defined for $x = -2$, even though $f(-2)$ is not defined. If you have paid to do this course, why don't you ask the tutors whose time you have paid for?

Comment: @RobArthan ohh. i just found an example online to illustrate the problem that i am talking about, not enrolled into any course. just googled and this popped up for me, i never had to sign up to view the page.

Comment: @RobArthan anyways i am attaching a screenshot of what is given in the link, pls check: Problem. https://ibb.co/bSG1Bc, Solution. https://ibb.co/iufpxH

Comment: @Math_QED Consider $(x^2-4)/(x-4)$. Since $x=4$ is in the domain, does it not make sense to talk about continuity at that point (or the lack thereof)?

Comment: @AndrewLi x = 4 is not in the domain...

Comment: @Math_QED Exactly, and it's has a removable discontinuity. Unless I'm misunderstanding your comment, you say it doesn't make sense to discuss continuity at something not in the domain, so does the removable discontinuity not exist?

Comment: I see your point, but there is no removable discontinuity here (look closely at the roots of numerator). I just meant that it does not make sense to talk about continuity at a point not in the domain, it does make sense to ask yourself the question whether a function can be continuously extended

Comment: Andrew Li ,Math_QED ,Rob Arthan my observations are based on the definition that a function is said to be discontinuous at a point when it is not continuous there. I think with that definition it is ok to say $1/x$ is discontinuous at $x=0$ as it does not satisfy the conditions of continuity at that point. pls check, @enzotib 's answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924770/why-is-y-1-x-a-continuous-function-but-not-y-1-x2

Comment: @Math_QED please check Ex:5 and Ex:6 in this reference http://math.mit.edu/~jspeck/18.01_Fall%202014/Supplementary%20notes/01c.pdf where it says "the function $1/x$ has a single point of discontinuity, namely x = 0, and it has an infinite discontinuity there"

Comment: By the way, your statement that "If $f$ and $g$ are both continuous at $x=a$ then it is said that the composite function $h(x)=f(g(x))$ must also be continuous at $x=a$" is false. The correct statement is that "If $g$ is continuous at $x=a$ and $f$ is continuous at $x=g(a)$, then the composite function $h(x)=f(g(x))$ must be continuous at $x=a$".

Comment: @zipirovich thnx. srry i didnt pay much attention to it, have edited. Could u pls comment on my doubt in the examples mentioned ?