# Does the composite function $h=f(g(x))$ share the discontinuity of $g(x)$?

Tags: calculus, continuity

For example,

Is the function $h(x)=f(f(x))$ discontinuous at $x=0$ if $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ ?

**My observation**

$h(x)=x$ is continuous at $x=0$

$f(f(x))=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$ is discontinuous at $x=0$ as $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.

The function $h(x)=x$ and $f(f(x))=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}$ are not exactly the same. Thus, though $h(x)=x$ is continuous, when we say the composite function $f(f(x))=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}=x$ we are already assuming the function is not defined at $x=0$, thus discontinuous at $x=0$.

Is my observation correct ?

Does this applies to similar composite functions, say $h(x)=f(g(x))$ where $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x-2}$ ?

**Similar Post**

In a similar problem [Discontinuity of composite function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729993/discontinuity-of-composite-function-fgx-where-fx-frac1x2x-2-and) , I do not find any explanation rather than few comments arguing the continuity of function $\frac{1}{x}$ does not make sense at $x=0$ and it is a continuous function as the limit exists in its domain. But, check [Example 5](http://math.mit.edu/~jspeck/18.01_Fall%202014/Supplementary%20notes/01c.pdf) clearly states "it is not a continuous function since its domain is not an interval. It has a single point of discontinuity, namely x = 0, and it has an infinite discontinuity there".

Comment: If a function $f$ is not defined at $x_0$, it doesn't have the property of being or not being continuous at that point. You can ask for a continuous extension though.

Comment: @Christoph pls check what is being explained in Example 5 in http://math.mit.edu/~jspeck/18.01_Fall%202014/Supplementary%20notes/01c.pdf

Comment: The definition of continuity of a function in those notes includes the domain being an interval. Note that this a rather non-standard definition.

Comment: h (x) is not equal to x but to $\frac {1}{\frac {1}{x}} $

Comment: That paper uses a non-standard definition of continuity. Usually, the limit notion of continuity is a _theorem_, not a definition.

Comment: why do i have a downvote !. Explaining that'd be helpful.

Comment: @Christoph there many resources which talking about $\frac{1}{x}$ being not continuous at $x=0$. What about infinite discontinuity ?. Is it not even a thing ?

Comment: @Arthur is it not what we call infinite discontinuity ?. http://www.mit.edu/~hlb/StantonGrant/Lecture2/infinitediscontinuities.pdf

Comment: Well, clearly, $f(x) = \frac1x$ is not continuous at $x = 0$, that we can agree on. However, I subscribe to a notion that it's not discontinuous either. It's just... not defined. There is definitely an asymptote at $x = 0$, though, and in some circumstances I would call it a pole. I guess you could call that an "infinite discontinuity", if you want.

Comment: @Arthur thanx for agreeing. This is something that i got stuck arguing  in my other post mentioned. In many problems i think they mean infinite discontinuity by saying it is discontinuous at $x=0$, So as $\frac{1}{x}$ not continuous at $x=0$. Could u  pls comment on whether my observation is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

In all your examples, you consider functions that are not defined at some point. If $f$ is not defined at $x=0$, then $g\circ f$ is not defined at $x=0$ either and therefore not continuous at $x=0$.

In more generality, if $f$ is defined over all $\Bbb R$, but not continuous, it may very well be that $g\circ f$ is continuous: this happens for example if $g$ is constant - but of course this is not necessary.