# From the discontinuity of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, can we directly tell about the discontinuity of $f(g(x))$?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, function-and-relation-composition

> From the discontinuity of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, can we directly tell about the discontinuity of $f(g(x))$?

I thought $f(g(x))$ would be discontinuous where $g(x)$ is discontinuous and where $g(x)=c$, where $c$ is the point of discontinuity of $f(x)$.

But this is not true. e.g.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1-x,&0\le x\le1\\x+2,&1\lt x\lt2\\4-x,&2\le x\le4\end{cases}$$

$f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=1$. As per my theory above, $f(f(x))$ should also be discontinuous at $x=1$. But this is not true.

But that theory is applicable on the following set of functions.

$f(x)=|2x-1|+|2x+1|$ and $g(x)$ being the fractional part of $x$.

Both $g(x)$ and $f(g(x))$ are discontinuous at $x=0$.

Can we generalize the above theory so that it captures all the cases?

Similar posts exist [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2730682/does-the-composite-function-h-fgx-share-the-discontinuity-of-gx) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729993/discontinuity-of-composite-function-fgx-where-fx-frac1x2x-2-and).

Comment: If $f$ is the fractional part function and $g$ is the floor function, both are discontinuous but their composite is constant (thus continuous)

Comment: You could of course generalize. Let's say $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)=u\ne v=\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and $g$ is continuous around $u,v$ and $g(u)\ne g(v)$, then $\lim_{x\to a^-}g(f(x))=g(u)\ne g(v)=\lim_{x\to a^+}g(f(x))$. Or, if $f(x)$ is continuous and monotonically increasing around $x=a$ and $\lim_{x\to f(a)-}g(x)=u\ne v=\lim_{x\to f(a)+}g(x)$ then $\lim_{x\to a^-}g(f(x))=u\ne v=\lim_{x\to a^+}g(f(x))$. In general, one of the functions is discontinuous (but with one-sided limits existing) and the other continuous, you can conclude things about their composition.

Answer (score 1):

Composition can mix things up rather weirdly. I'd be surprised if there is any good "theory" at all.

Here is an example to ponder. Consider a real number $c \in \mathbb R$ and a partition of $\mathbb R$ into three subsets $\mathbb R = A \sqcup B \sqcup C$ such that $B=A+c=\{x+c \mid x \in A\}$ and such that $A,B,C$ are all dense. For example we can take $A = \mathbb Q$ and $B=\mathbb Q+\sqrt{2}$ and $C=\mathbb R - \bigl(\mathbb Q \cup (\mathbb Q + \sqrt{2})\bigr)$.

Define
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x + c & \text{if $x \in A$} \\
x - c &\text{if $x \in B=A+c$} \\
x & \text{if $x \in C = \mathbb R - (A \cup B)$}
\end{cases}
$$
Notice that $f$ is discontinuous at every point.

Now let $g(x)=f(x)$. Still discontinuous at every point.

Finally, note that $f(g(x))=x$, which is continuous at every point.