# Spivak's Calculus Chapter $7$ $15$b) Prove $f$ is bounded below

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Q15) Suppose that $\phi$ is continuous and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n})=0=\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}(\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n})$

b) Prove that if $n$ is even, then there is a number $y$ such that $y^n + \phi(y) \leq x^n + \phi(x)$ for all $x$.

I have been wrestling with the question all day but can't get the result. In fact not only did I not get the result, I'm becoming convinced it's false. For example, say $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Then $\phi$ is continuous and satisfies the limits above, but $x^n + \frac{1}{x}$ doesn't have a lower bound because $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-}(x^n + \frac{1}{x}) = -\infty$. Unless $\frac{1}{x}$ is not continuous at $0$, ok, but when we say a function is continuous, don't we mean specifically it's continuous on the domain on which it's defined? I'm pretty sure I'm wrong somewhere. How do we solve this question?

Comment: And for your specific question : when we say that $\phi$ is continuous, it means "continuous *everywhere* ". So your counterexample does not work because $\phi $is indeed not continuous (even not defined !) at $0$.

Comment: I thought of that possibility and looked it up and found the opposite result. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924770/why-is-y-1-x-a-continuous-function-but-not-y-1-x2

Comment: I guess it depends on context then.

Comment: You are right, but here, $\phi$ must be defined and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** The function $$x \mapsto x^n + \phi(x)$$

is continuous and tends to $+\infty$ when $x$ tends to $\pm \infty$. It is sufficient to ensure that it has a minimum.